# Reuse built-in Firefox icons in XUL extension?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, icons, xul, built-in

Is there an easy way to use the built-in icons of the Firefox browser, such as the add, remove, or refresh icon, in a XUL firefox extension? I would like to use the icons in a toolbar to be consistent with the browser design.

I have been looking high and low for an answer, but the web is strangely devoid of this little piece of information. Therefore it must either be dead simple or not possible. I hope the former...

Thanks already for all your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The resources, such as icons, are accessible from add-ons.
E.g. the browser reload icon is at `chrome://browser/skin/reload-stop-go.png` (you can open this in your Firefox). This particular icon would be used in conjunction with [`-moz-image-rect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-image-rect) bases sprite-ing.

Icons are usually specified in the CSS rules for the `browser` (Firefox) or the `global` package (aka. toolkit). To find out where something is, I'd recommend the [DOM Inspector](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/dom-inspector-6622/) add-on, inspecting the Chrome window itself and looking in particular at the CSS and/or computed styles view. Also, you may look directly in the source, e.g. on [MXR](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/themes/).

Word of advice: Should you always double-check that browser/toolkit resources are actually available on all platforms and are accessed the same way, have the same URI, dimensions in case of icons, and so on. In particular with add-ons, quite often the platform themes will use platform icons (e.g. GTK stock icons on linux) or provide multiple alternatives (Win aero and regular icons, or regular and @2x hidpi ones).

Comment: Sorry for accepting your answer so very late. I had moved on to a different project by the time the answer came and did not check on SO.